# Lines in Noise texture

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, shader-nodes, text-object

I am trying to add a noise texture to my letters to make them have a partially emissive texture that I can then move throughout the animation over the letters. However the noise texture is barely visible, and if I scale it up it does not show up with dots as usual but rather in irregular lines. I added a box and there it worked normally, and I have tried to rescale the uv maps. I already set the location and oration of the letters throughout the animation, does that have smith to do with it?
Here is what it looks like with noise texture on the box versus text, and the second one scaled up to be visible[image]. [image]

Comment: please show us your uv or provide blend file. thx

Comment: In your first screenshot, you have connected the 3-dimensional Vector Mapping output to the 1-dimensional Scale input. This, combined with the non-uniform scaling parameters in the Vector Mapping, possibly leads to the weird lines.

Also, you are not using the UVs from your Texture Coordinate Node...

Comment: @LaserLars that deserves a full post below. Care to flesh it out into a formal answer?